# Не получаю размер файла при загрузке через Multer. Как его получить?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Загружаю файл через Multer на сервер Node JS. Когда хочу отфильтровать файл по весу через fileFilter, то объект file не содержит свойства size. Почему? По документации он должен быть, а его нет.

Логи из Middleware avatar дают сделующее:

```
console.log(req.file);
console.log(file);
```

```
undefined
{
  fieldname: 'avatar',
  originalname: 'football-157930_640.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png'
}
```

А по документации должно быть больше полей: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/doc/README-ru.md#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85

Клиентская часть кода:

```
btnSaveAvatar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#avatar_progress').classList.remove('hide');

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('avatar', document.querySelector('#input_new_avatar').files[0]);

  fetch('/profile/new-avatar', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'CSRF-Token': tokenCSRF
    },
    body: formData
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    if (result.status === 'error') {
      document.querySelector('#avatar_progress').classList.add('hide');
      alert(`Ошибка: ${result.description}`);
    }
    if (result.status === 'success') {
      document.querySelector('#avatar_progress').classList.add('hide');
      document.querySelector('#avatar_profile').src = result.avatarURL;
      document.querySelector('#avatar_sidenav').src = result.avatarURL;
      document.querySelector('#btn_delete_avatar').classList.remove('disabled');
    }
  })
  .catch(err => alert(`Ошибка: ${err}`));
});
```

Серверная часть кода:

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const redirectToIndexIfNotAuthenticated = require('../middleware/redirectToIndexIfNotAuthenticated');
const User = require('../models/user');
const router = Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const avatar = require('../middleware/avatar');

router.post('/new-avatar', redirectToIndexIfNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let upload = avatar.single('avatar');

    upload(req, res, async (err) => {

      if (req.fileValidationError) {
        return res.json({
          status: 'error',
          description: req.fileValidationError
        });
      } else if (!req.file) {
        return res.json({
          status: 'error',
          description: 'Вы не выбрали аватар.'
        });
      } else if (err) {
        return res.json({
          status: 'error',
          description: err
        });
      }
  
      const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

      if (user.avatarURL) {
        fs.unlink(user.avatarURL, async (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
    
          user.avatarURL = req.file.path;
          await user.save();
    
          res.json({
            status: 'success',
            avatarURL: req.file.path
          });
        });
      } else {
        user.avatarURL = req.file.path;
        await user.save();
  
        res.json({
          status: 'success',
          avatarURL: req.file.path
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Middleware avatar:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'avatars');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(file);

  if (!['image/png', 'image/jpeg'].includes(file.mimetype)) {
    req.fileValidationError = 'Изображение должно быть в формате PNG, JPG или JPEG.';
    return cb(new Error('Изображение должно быть в формате PNG, JPG или JPEG.'), false);
  }

  if (file.size > 2097152) {
    req.fileValidationError = 'Изображение должно быть не более 2 МБ.';
    return cb(new Error('Изображение должно быть не более 2 МБ.'), false);
  }
  
  cb(null, true);
}

module.exports = multer({
  storage, fileFilter
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Размер файла в байтах хранится в `req.file.size`:

```js
upload(req, res, async err => {
  console.log(req.file.size) // file size
});
```

Comment: Но ведь логичнее проверять размер файла внутри fileFilter. А там req.file целиком равен undefined. Я написал это выше, в логах. Почему так получается?

Comment: @Alexal, в конце [этой статьи](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/10.2.php) это описано

Comment: Но ведь лог выполняется до вызова колбека